# Listing items with item itself having comma

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists

> We looked at potential publishers for this paper, including European Conference on
> Object-Oriented Programming, Object-oriented Programming, Systems,
> Languages, and Applications, and IEEE
> Transactions on Software Engineering.

The publisher "Object-oriented Programming, Systems, Languages, and Applications" itself has commas in its name.

I'm wondering if readers may think I'm looking at 6 publishers instead of 3.

What techniques or symbols can I use to avoid confusions?

Is using quotes a good way? If yes, can I use it with shorter items, like

> My favourite pies are "chicken, ham and mushroom" and "apple".

Comment: I like your edit, @Andrew

Comment: Many (unsubstantiated claim) would use a semicolon (ie *;*) to separate items in a list where the items themselves contain commas, so *European Conference on Object-Oriented Programming; Object-oriented Programming, Systems, Languages, and Applications; and IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering.* for the example given.

Comment: There are several similar questions already on SE; if you search for terms like *comma, list, semicolon* you'll find them; as mentioned above, semicolons can help. Does this answer your question? [Which punctuation is correct in this case (colon, semicolon, or period)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261056/which-punctuation-is-correct-in-this-case-colon-semicolon-or-period)

Comment: 'Do I use semicolons to create a list where there are commas in the items?' is the most obvious duplicate as regards title questions, but is itself a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of Editorial Guidelines or Other Standards, but I use "Itemizing" or "listing" or "numbering" in such cases.

> We looked at potential publishers for this paper, including (A) European Conference on Object-Oriented Programming, (B) Object-oriented Programming, Systems, Languages, and Applications, and (C) IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering.

Preference is to use (1) (2) (3) when there are many more list Items.

Alternatives:
I have seen usage of Semicolon ( mentioned by user High Performance Mark ) but this might not be visible at a glance.
Possibility of using of quotes is restricted to certain cases.
We could also insert extra information in square brackets at the end of names, in some cases:

> We looked at potential publishers for this paper, including European Conference on Object-Oriented Programming [Published Monthly], Object-oriented Programming, Systems, Languages, and Applications [Published Yearly], and IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering [Published Quarterly].

Overall, "Itemizing" or "numbering" or "listing" is very general and easy to use while being easy to read too.

Comment: Bullet-formatting is even clearer. Personally, I find unreformatted numbering an untidy hybrid (though I'm reduced to using it in 'comments' here). But all this has been addressed before on ELU.